# Access Typedef in Function From Outside

Tags: c++, function, c++11, typedef

I am working on some math related objects, and I would love to be able to distinguish between operators which behave in mathematical ways.  The simplest solution, and one I hope can somehow be accomplished is below.

```
struct derp { };

derp operator+(derp const & a, derp const & b) {
    typedef std::true_type commutative;
    typedef std::true_type associative;

    return derp();
}

void test() {
    typedef int testing;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // is it possible to access test::testing or the typedef's in the operator+ from here?

    return 0;
}
```

Is this or something similar possible?

Comment: what do you mean by access. a typedef doesn't actually instantiate a variable.  It nearly defines a data type, so there isn't anything to access.   If you mean you would like to use those datatypes that is different.

Comment: I need access to the type for template metaprogramming purposes

Comment: No you can't since `test` is not a class. Try to define a class with `test` as a member and `testing` also as a member but outside of `test`. Also the notation `test::testing` is not right (`test` is not a class).

Comment: I know it isn't right, that's basically the question.  I was hoping some notation would allow me to use typedefs defined inside a function

Comment: The scope operator expects a namespace or a typename as a left argument. If you get the typedef out of the test function it should be possible to call it by derp::testing. Otherwise it would be local to the test member function preventing you from using the scope operator.

Comment: Here is an example of how you can use it http://pastebin.com/3c2Nd884.

Answer (score 0):

No. `typedef`s within a function are local to the scope of the function.

A way to provide similar functionality would be to define an external type (could also be a nested type) that defines what you want.

One possible way:

```
template<typename T>
struct arithmetic_traits
{
    using addition_associate = std::false_type;
    using addition_commutative = std::false_type;
};

template<>
struct arithmetic_traits<derp>
{
    using addition_associate = std::true_type;
    using addition_commutative = std::true_type;
};
```